# Get Substring of A String with Spaces and Quotes using IndexOf

Tags: java, indexof, lastindexof

I have the following String and would like to extract the contents of rule i.e. My Rule Description Looks Like This:

```
rule "My Rule Description Looks Like This"      
        followed by some white space other characters such as quotes".
```

When i use the following I get a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2:

```
String ruleName = rule.substring(rule.indexOf("rule \"" + 7, rule.indexOf("\""));
```

and when i use lastIndexOf:

```
String ruleName = rule.substring(rule.indexOf("rule \"" + 7, rule.lastIndexOf("\""));
```

the code executes OK but the output looks like:

```
My Rule Description Looks Like This"        
        followed by some white space other characters and quotes
```

Any ideas why the first option throws an exception using indexOf?

Comment: You're calling something that looks like `substring(11, 4)`

Comment: your substring calls do not compile.

Comment: Surprised no one has mentioned that `"rule \"" + 7` is literally the string `"rule "7"`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Count the parenthesis, it's missing one. That's just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any sort of complex text extraction, you might want to consider using regular expressions.  Here is a short script which can extract the rule, and it avoids nasty string manipulations, which, as you have seen, can be prone to error.

```
String line = "rule \"My Rule Description Looks Like This\"\n";
line += "followed by some white space other characters such as quotes\".";
String pattern = "rule\\s+\"(.*?)\".*";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println("Found a rule: " + m.group(1) );
} else {
   System.out.println("Could not find a rule.");
}
```

**Output:**

```
My Rule Description Looks Like This
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, i'll look into using a pattern instead.

Comment: Check the other answers if you want to see where you went wrong with `String#substring()`, but if your requirement gets any more complex than this, then regex is probably a better investment of your time.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

> public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
>
> if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

You are calling `rule.substring(rule.indexOf("rule \"" + 7, rule.indexOf("\""))`. The first parameter gives you the index of the first `rule + quote`, let's say `x`, + 7. The second parameter gives you the index of the first quote, which is `x + 6` (`x` - the number of characters in `rule` . So you are calling `substring (x + 7, x +6)`, which falls in the exception case:

> first parameter biger than the second.

In you rsecond case, using `lastIndexOf`, you are getting the second quote, so you don't have this problem.

Comment: This is incorrect. The first parameter to indexOf is a string; therefore, `"rule \"" + 7` is literally the string `"rule "7"`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis As he got an exception and not an error, you can assume he wrote `String ruleName = rule.substring(rule.indexOf("rule \"") + 7, rule.indexOf("\""));`.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns the index of the **first occurrence** of the specified String.

So your first example would try to substring starting from index 7 (0 is the index of where your String is found, and then you add 7), and ending at index 5 (where the first " is found).

The `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` method has some logic in it where if the begin index subtracted from the end index is < 0 
 it will throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` with the value:

```
int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
if (subLen < 0) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
}
```

Your second example doesn't throw an exception, but because you are using `lastIndexOf()` it will substring from 7 to the end of the String (where there is a ").

The best solution would be to use a regex pattern like shown in @Tim Biegeleisen's answer